# How to reduce columns for a nested property in feature collection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to obtain the mean (and max and min) of a set of properties in a `featureCollection`, except these properties are nested within a larger category which is precluding me from using `.reduceColumns()` directly.

What would be the shortest way to do this without having to reformat the `featureCollection` (if that's possible)?

Below is an MVP for testing.

```
var exampleFC = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null,{
    propertyGroup: {
      val1: 10,
      val2: 5,
      val3: 40
    }
  }),
  ee.Feature(null,{
    propertyGroup: {
      val1: 11,
      val2: 32,
      val3: 4
    }
  }),
  ee.Feature(null,{
    propertyGroup: {
      val1: 22,
      val2: 53,
      val3: 7
    }
  }),
]);
print('exampleFC',exampleFC);

var valuesStats = exampleFC.reduceColumns({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().repeat(3),
  selectors: ['val1','val2','val3']
})
print('valuesStats',valuesStats) //Currently returns null values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to map over the features and either pull the properties up or push them down into a new feature.

```
var result = exampleFC.map(function(f) {
   // Pull properties up to the top level of the original feature
   return f.set(f.get('propertyGroup'))

   // or push them down into a new feature.
   return ee.Feature(null, f.get('propertyGroup'))
})
```

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thank you!